# jqtransform plugin not responding

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm using jqTransform plugin to apply styles for my textboxes, radio buttons, checkboxes.

The problem is that it's working for forms only, not for individual input fields.

Check out this link: http://www.dfc-e.com/metiers/multimedia/opensource/jqtransform/

They used:

```
$('form').jqTransform({imgPath:'jqtransformplugin/img/'});
```

I changed that to:

```
$('#muDivId').jqTransform({imgPath:'jqtransformplugin/img/'});
```

The image paths are all correct but it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

check with firebug

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just try one insert a `<div>` tag and

```
<div id='imgdiv'> Add your image tag here</div>
```

while loading the page:

```
$('#imgdiv').jqTransform({imgPath:'jqtransformplugin/img/'});
```